# Parse for Xamarin error on log in

Tags: android, parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.android

So I am using Parse SDK for Xamarin on an Android App, and when I try to login it shows an error in the console and nothing happens. This is how the error looks:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uriString
  at System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString) [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/0a4ab557/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/URI.cs:406 
  at Parse.Internal.ParseCommand..ctor (System.String relativeUri, System.String method, System.String sessionToken, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] headers, System.IO.Stream stream, System.String contentType) [0x00014] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
  at Parse.Internal.ParseCommand..ctor (System.String relativeUri, System.String method, System.String sessionToken, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] headers, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] data) [0x00000] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
  at Parse.Internal.ParseUserController.LogInAsync (System.String username, System.String password, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00030] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
  at Parse.ParseUser.LogInAsync (System.String username, System.String password, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00005] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
  at Parse.ParseUser.LogInAsync (System.String username, System.String password) [0x00007] in <5d1c0c2b96a7483d85e5c63b3e156125>:0 
  at ViroMusicApp.MainActivity+<logIn>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00034] in /Users/ctabuyo/Desktop/Viro App/Android Project/ViroMusicApp/ViroMusicApp/Controller/MainActivity.cs:44
```

This is my Log In method:

```
private async void logIn(string Username, string Password)
        {
            try
            {
                await ParseUser.LogInAsync(username: Username, password: Password);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }


        }
```

I am using Visual Studio for Mac Preview

Thanks!

Comment: You have to roll your own parse server backend now. The official servers have been shut down. http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seams that you didn´t setup the server url correctly.
Make sure you do that before calling to your login() method.

```
var config = new ParseClient.Configuration
{
    ApplicationId = "xxxx",
    Server = "http://xxxxxx"
};

ParseClient.Initialize(config);
```